# Testcafe - How to call a excel data driven class from main class in testcafe?

Tags: excel, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Getting "cannot read "forEach' undefined. I have implemented as you said. but still, I am getting errors. Pls give a solution for this

//data-driven script in a separate class

```
import xlsx from "node-xlsx"

 // read logic of excel
export function readDataFromExcelFile(filePath) {
  const excelFile = xlsx.parse(filePath)
  const excelSheet = excelFile.find((sheets) => sheets.name == 
  "sheetname")
  const excelSheetData = excelSheet.data

  const headers = excelSheetData.shift()
  const dataSet = excelSheetData.map((row) => {
    const user = {}

    row.forEach((data, idx) => (user[headers[idx]] = data))

    return user
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you're basically trying to implement data-driven tests with TestCafé. In your case, the data source seem to be Excel files. Assuming that you have the code to read from excel files in one JavaScript file:

```js
// This is your file that contains your excel reading code, such as excel.js
import xlsx from "node-xlsx"

// the export keyword is necessary for the function so that it can be imported within other files 
export function readDataFromExcelFile(filePath) {
 // your excel file reading code goes here
}
```

Add the following code to your JavaScript file containing the test code to iterate over your dataSet that you previously retrieved from your Excel files and make whatever actions and assertions you need to do, based on your data:

```js
import { readDataFromExcelFile} from './excel.js'; // import excel reading function from excel.js

// Create a fixture (test-suite) for your your data-driven tests
fixture `My data-driven tests`
    .page `https://www.mySampleUrl/further/stuff/`;

const dataSet = readDataFromExcelFile("path/to/your/excel.xlsx")

// iterate over the dataSet that was previously returned from your readDataFromExcelFile function
dataSet.forEach(data => {
    // Create & execute a test for each dataSet entry
    test(`Test for'${data.someTestIdentifier}'`, async t => {
      // Your test specific content. Test actions and assertions/validations come here
      await t.expect(Selector("h1").textContent).eql(data.someDataEntry);
    });
});
```

Take a further look into data-driven Tests with TestCafé [here](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402804/recipes/best-practices/create-data-driven-tests).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I have all the logic for the script. The only thing is I want to keep the excel data read logics separately and use them in test scripts(main class). So how can I link the main class and the excel data-driven class?

Comment: So if I get you correctly, you want to separate your data reading actions from your tests, which is good practice. The only thing you need to do then is to export the method/function that returns your desired dataset in the file that is defined, and import it in the file that you have your tests defined in. If that is what you want to achieve, I can update my answer in this regard.

Comment: @Ajith I updated my answer accordingly. Hopefully it fits your needs now.

Comment: Martin.. I have found the mistake I made. I missed returning the const.  now it's working after I returned the const. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hey @Ajith , glad to hear that! If this setup works fine for you and answers your question, it would be cool if you accept the answer.

Comment: Hey @Ajith, there surely is, but that is not a TestCafe related topic. For that, you‘ll have to take a deeper look into the capabilities of the node-xlsx library that you use.